# IllegalStateException: in SimpleFrameBuilder when running grails app in tcserver w/ insight

Tags: tcserver, spring-insight

I am trying to profile a grails application using insight.

- Grails - 2.4.0 or 2.4.1 (tried 2.4.1 to see if it fixed my issue)
- GGTS - 3.5.0 w/ eclipse 4.3.2
- tcserver - VMWare vFabric tc Server Developer Edition (Runtime) v2.9 
  (from within eclipse)
- PermGenSpace = 1024m

I have tried the following;

- Drag the grails application from the project explorer and drop it on the tc server in the Servers pane
- Build the grails application with grails dev war and placed the war file into the webapps directory directly via command line
- Run As -> Run on Server

I'm seeing the same result, which is the stacktrace below. Anybody have an thoughts as to what might be wrong or how to make this work? If more information is needed, please let me and I'll try to provide it.

Thanks much!

Thantous

EDIT:

Got the server to startup by adjusting the memory of the tcserver. The real issues stopping the server from starting was the heap memory error at the very bottom of the stacktrace. I am still seeing the error for SimepleFrameBuilder, but at least the server starts up now :).

Here is the relevant part of the server config for memory settings;

-Xmx2048m -Xss1024k -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m

-- StackTrace --

```
2014-06-25 09:13:40,995 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR errorhandling.CollectionErrors  - Disabling aspect com.springsource.insight.plugin.springcore.ClassPathScanOperationCollectionAspect
- IllegalStateException: current frame builder doesn't support frame discarding class com.springsource.insight.intercept.trace.SimpleFrameBuilder 

2014-06-25 09:13:41,010 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR errorhandling.AdviceErrorHandlingAspect  - Error swallowed in advice adviceexecution(void com.springsource.insight.collection.AbstractOperationCollectionAspect.afterReturning(Object, JoinPoint.StaticPart)) 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: current frame builder doesn't support frame discarding class com.springsource.insight.intercept.trace.SimpleFrameBuilder 

at com.springsource.insight.intercept.trace.collapse.CollapsingFrameBuilder.getFirstCollapsedFrame(CollapsingFrameBuilder.java:183)     

at com.springsource.insight.intercept.trace.collapse.CollapsingFrameBuilder.collapseIfRequired(CollapsingFrameBuilder.java:150)     

at com.springsource.insight.intercept.trace.collapse.CollapsingFrameBuilder.exit(CollapsingFrameBuilder.java:72)    

at com.springsource.insight.intercept.trace.ThreadLocalFrameBuilder.exit(ThreadLocalFrameBuilder.java:93)   

at com.springsource.insight.collection.overflow.CountOperationsTraceOverflowStrategy.doExit(CountOperationsTraceOverflowStrategy.java:196)  

at com.springsource.insight.collection.overflow.CountOperationsTraceOverflowStrategy.exit(CountOperationsTraceOverflowStrategy.java:91)     

at com.springsource.insight.collection.DefaultOperationCollector.exit(DefaultOperationCollector.java:161)   

at com.springsource.insight.collection.DefaultOperationCollector._exitNormal(DefaultOperationCollector.java:74)     

at com.springsource.insight.collection.DefaultOperationCollector.exitNormal(DefaultOperationCollector.java:65)  

at com.springsource.insight.collection.AbstractOperationCollectionAspect.ajc$afterReturning$com_springsource_insight_collection_AbstractOperationCollectionAspect$2$34342d20_aroundBody2(AbstractOperationCollectionAspect.aj:105)  

at com.springsource.insight.collection.AbstractOperationCollectionAspect$AjcClosure3.run(AbstractOperationCollectionAspect.aj:1)    

at com.springsource.insight.collection.errorhandling.AdviceErrorHandlingAspect.ajc$around$com_springsource_insight_collection_errorhandling_AdviceErrorHandlingAspect$1$e76a6b03proceed(AdviceErrorHandlingAspect.aj:41)    

at com.springsource.insight.collection.errorhandling.AdviceErrorHandlingAspect.ajc$around$com_springsource_insight_collection_errorhandling_AdviceErrorHandlingAspect$1$e76a6b03(AdviceErrorHandlingAspect.aj:43)   

at com.springsource.insight.collection.AbstractOperationCollectionAspect.ajc$afterReturning$com_springsource_insight_collection_AbstractOperationCollectionAspect$2$34342d20(AbstractOperationCollectionAspect.aj:1)    

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)  

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)  

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[error 2014/06/25 09:14:45.735 PDT <GemfireHeapPoller> tid=0x23] Member: gamera(5640:loner):0:eb9aced3 above critical heap threshold
```